# AngularJS SPA Template

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I've been reading alot about AngularJS and I just absobutely love the concept behind it and want to get my feet wet. I've read up on several tutorials and eventually downloaded Visual Studio Template SPA and that's where the "fun" stops. The way I see it - using that template seems to go against the grain of creating a SPA - there are very little examples to go on.

By default, the SPA Template installed sets up this like:

```
app
app_start
Content
Images
Routing
Scripts
  Vendor
  app.js
  controller.js
  (the rest you get the idea)
Views
you get the idea.
```

The question is really bugging me. For example,I want to insert a hockey player and coach page (two separate SPA) to work under the current masterpage content. This is where I'm a bit lost on "separation"

The way I see it, I would have to add a route to app.js and a controller to controller.js for coach and player but I don't like that because I want to separate the player and coach controller code and put it under the player and coach modules like this.

But what I tried to do and fail is:

```
Module
   Player
      playerApp.js
      playerControl.js
      player.cshtml
   Coach
      coachApp.js
      coachControl.js
      coach.cshtml
```

I'm struggling to "hook" them up. I certainly do not want to put the coach controller and the player controller in the control.js file under the scripts folder and the views (player and coach) under the Views folder. It would become too difficult to read and eventually become messy.

Any guidance would be appreciate on what I should be reading on.

thanks,

Comment: Your example structure looks good . Aside from separating the script files from the cshtml files, that's the way I would do it. Use gulp or grunt to bundle and minify the script files into one.

Comment: Exactly - but how do I route it in the code? I'm trying to find examples...that is what I'm looking for - that lightbulb moment..:-)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what code do I put in playerControll.cs and playerApp.js to route under the masterpage template...do I copy and paste what was in the scripts folder app.js and controller.js and change the routing parameters and change the app to playerApp at the header of the app.js under player folder...?

Comment: its hard to grasp what the challenges are, maybe provide a simplified example?

Comment: if you opened up the controller.js and app.js in the default template, you will see the existing code that points to the "app" which is the master page. The question is do I take the code that is in the app.js and the controller.js and paste it behind the playerApp.js and the playerController.js and modify accordingly to fit the player module? Where do I place the route to player.cshtl view? Do I place it in the default app.js and refer to the controller under the player module (playerController.js) instead of the default controller.js?

Comment: If you have different cshtml files, I would put a playerApp.js and a coachApp.js, and their corresponding controllers. I would get rid of app.js and controller.js.  Each server-side page load should have its own app module

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat of an opinionated question and answer, but I want to offer one possible scenario which I have found works well.

Unless you have a compelling need for Razor (i.e. existing user controls), your path of least resistance is to not use ASP.Net MVC at all.  Instead, you can leverage ASP.Net WebAPI, which operates similarly to MVC, but provides a REST interface to handle JSON data instead of using Views and Server Routing.

In your Web App, you can simply use a single `index.html` which can be hooked up with angular, and your individual modules can be separated without needlessly being concerned with multiple "app" pages, how to interact between them, etc.

On the server, you can either run the WebAPI from a different URL, or more commonly, from something like `http://yoursite.com/api/`.  IIS would be configured to redirect anything that is not static files (.css, .js, images, etc.) or api calls back to the single `index.html`.